# Baciato vs Baciata

Tags: verbs, gender, agreement, auxiliary-verb, past-participle

Se devo dire che ho baciato una ragazza, cosa devo dire?

1. L'ho baciato
2. L'ho baciata

Il primo mi sembra più corretto, perché sta per "ho baciato lei", però sento sempre dire il secondo.  Quale dei due è corretto?
Chiaramente questo è solo un esempio stupido, ma la questione si pone per ogni verbo transitivo (oltre a 'baciare').

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Premesso che classicamente l'italiano in molti casi preferisce la concordanza del participio con il complemento oggetto, in certe situazioni possono essere lecite entrambe le possibilità: «abbiamo scelte le più belle», come scrive Pirandello, oppure «abbiamo scelto le più belle», come diremmo oggi.

Ma nel caso che proponi non c'è alcun dubbio che l'unica forma corretta è quella con la concordanza («L'ho baciata»). Cito dalla grammatica italiana di Serianni (pag. 322 dell'edizione nella “Garzantina”):

> Si ha ... obbligo di accordo quando il participio si riferisca a uno dei seguenti pronomi atoni precedenti: *lo*, *la*, *li*, *le*. Esempi: «io vedo sempre lui che me *l'ha data*, questa libertà» (Pirandello, *Il giuoco delle parti*, III 33); «Di quei funghi si fece, in famiglia, un gran parlare: e i miei fratelli dissero alla mia nonna paterna [...] che *li avremmo cucinati* e *mangiati*» (Ginzburg, *Lessico famigliare*, 31).

Answer (score 0):

"L'ho baciato" is used when a girl has kissed a man, on the contrary, "l'ho baciata" is used when a man has kissed a girl.

I'm Italian! Bye!

Comment: in this way you are automatically excluding same-sex kisses and this is all unclear. The point here is not the gender of the person but the grammatical gender of the noun, and, even more precisely, that of the receiver of the action.