# Participle declension with object

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, agreement, auxiliary-verb, past-participle

I know in the case of only "essere" as an auxiliary verb, the past participle should have agreement with gender or number of subject, but in this sentences there are no subjects in both two sentences and with the same auxiliary verb  "avere" **Once** it has declension and agrees with object and **another time** it doesn't! 
Why participle here (lasciato) doesn't correspond with direct object in the case of gender

> Ieri mi ha lasciato (without correspondence with "La macchina") di nuovo a piedi.

while in following sentence (descritta) it does?

> Da come me l'ha descritta (correspondence with "la macchina della mia amica") credo che sia un'occasione.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Baciato vs Baciata](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/baciato-vs-baciata) and of [Past participle and changing endings with auxiliary verb “avere”](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/54/past-participle-and-changing-endings-with-auxiliary-verb-avere).

Comment: And, anyhow, in *Ieri mi ha lasciato ... a piedi* the agreement of *lasciato* is with the object (not the subject) of the sentence, who seemingly is a male. A woman would say *...mi ha lasciata...*

Comment: @DaG In both sentences the subject is absent! And the we should check the agreement with "object"!

Comment: @DaG, The referred question only talks about "No agreement with subject in the case of *avere*  "

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment, but the answers to both questions explicitly explain the only agreement your sentences need, that with the object (*complemento oggetto*). Did you read them? If they leave something unexplained, please adjust consequently your question.

Comment: Oh!! I found the precise answer in "Modern Italian Grammar" book!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the case of object with the pronouns that are placed as "object" (such as lo, la, li, le) the agreement is essential:

> Da come me l'ha descritta (correspondence with "la macchina della mia amica") credo che sia un'occasione.

But, in other case, If we have a conjunction:
a) the verb is not reflexive, the agreement is optional:

> *La frutta che Carla ha comprato(a)*

b)In the case of reflexive verb, it doesn't have agreement or declension:

> *Il libro che Carla si è comprata*

And the last case (where these conditions above don't occur, the past participle doesn't agree with object; so we don't have declension in this third case.

Comment: Your ideas on the topic don't seem to be too clear, or you are not explaining them clearly... For instance, are you sure that in the first sentence *la* refers to *la mia amica*? In which sense is a female friend a bargain...? Secondly, in the last seventy years almost nobody would say *La frutta che Carla ha comprata*. In the third sentence, *there is* some agreement, since *comprata* is feminine. And so on. Please, re-read the other answers on the same subject.

Comment: It exactly refers to _la machina della mia amica_ which both are feminine, I know you don't believe in me so read the whole sentence: "Mia amica vende la sua macchina, e da come me l'ho descritta credo che sia un'occasione." And in the case of second argument, If you really think "almost nobody would say _che Carla ha comprata_ " , here's another example of the same book: "I giornali che Carla ha comprato(i). "