# In which verbs does the participle carry gender?

Tags: grammar, orthography

If addressing a female person we say

> Sei arrivat*a* ? Sei tornat*a* ? etc,

that is, the participle needs to be declined into feminine form. We don't say, however

> Hai mangiat*a* ? Hai dormit*a* ? etc.

Is it only for movement or essere verbs that the participle takes gender ?

Comment: This has been asked several times: start from here and follow back the duplicates: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7601/participle-declension-with-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past participle and changing endings with auxiliary verb "avere"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/54/past-participle-and-changing-endings-with-auxiliary-verb-avere)

Comment: @DaG To some extent. Apparently it does change only with transitive verbs. I am, however, looking for exceptions or more authoritative answers.